# My Android app is getting synced successfully but when running the app then giving error Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle

**app\build.gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
//    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.29.0'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
//    debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error Log when application is executed.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource
>   compilation failed
>
> C:\Users\128953.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0.aar\bcaf2691803e4aceded82ce44741aa87\res\values\values.xml:168:5-120:
>   AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTint' with config
>   ''.
>            C:\Users\128953.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0.aar\bcaf2691803e4aceded82ce44741aa87\res\values\values.xml:168:5-120:
>   AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
>            C:\Users\128953.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\e266a3de4bfa13bf456f367854478beb\res\values\values.xml:987:5-1006:25:
>   AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTint' with config
>   ''.
>            C:\Users\128953.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\e266a3de4bfa13bf456f367854478beb\res\values\values.xml:987:5-1006:25:
>   AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
>            C:\Users\128953.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\e266a3de4bfa13bf456f367854478beb\res\values\values.xml:987:5-1006:25:
>   AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTintMode' with
>   config ''.
>            C:\Users\128953.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\e266a3de4bfa13bf456f367854478beb\res\values\values.xml:987:5-1006:25:
>   AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
>          Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
>   to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s 13 actionable tasks: 12 executed, 1 up-to-date

Comment: Did you play with permissions of SDK directory? specially `platform-tools` dir

Comment: try clean project and `invalidate caches and restart the project`

Answer (score 0):

as your error said :

> duplicate value for resource 'attr/iconTint' with config ''.

so you have two or more attribute with name iconTint . just check your ressource and you can fix it with finding duplicate

Comment: I am unable to find where these resources are declared so that I can fix them, can you help me to find those.

Comment: @Deepesh you can move in android studio to res->values->attrs.xml

Comment: there isn't any attrs.xml file under res -> values

Comment: @Deepesh ok. check colors.xml if not in there check other xml file but i think iconTint is in colors.xml

Comment: No, iconTint name isn't there in any app xml files. I think it's defined somewhere in the libraries I am using, can this cause problem ?

Comment: @Deepesh i don't think so. try to search in your res folder with ctrl+shift+f. if you add full source of library this may cause the problem but you don't do that as i see

Comment: thanks for letting me know the shortcut as it helps a bit to find the term across files but I am not able to see this resource under app..

Comment: Can you try this - File-> Invalidate Cache and Restart

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a duplicated value for resource 'attr/iconTint'.
The issue is related to the fact that this value exists both in design-28.0.0 and in appcompat-v7-28.0.0.

Try to invalidate the cache and restart Using the File menu od Android studio. 
If the issue continues, consider removing appcompat dependency as it should be already included in the design dependency.

Answer (score -1):

It clealy shows that issue with ***Res*** folder . in your exception clearly shows that ***values*** folder has duplicated value ***iconTint***. so remove that duplicate value. Keep coding :)